# simulate hdmi/displayport “unplug” + “re-plug” from shell

Tags: linux, graphics-card, nvidia-graphics-card, xorg, i3-window-manager

I'd like to ~duplicate "unplug, re-plug hdmi/displayport cable from monitor", via shell.

Obviously there may/will be some differences in result from real physical plug event.  Also, it may take several seconds to execute.  That's OK; my alternative ATM is to logout (nonstarter) or contort myself behind the monitor to re-plug a displayport.

My setup: two 4k monitors on `i3` (`regolith` variant) on `X` on `Ubuntu 20.04` with `nvidia-driver-440` on `GeForce gtx 1060`.

Underlying problem:

Including immediately after clean-install of `ubuntu`, i've had issues with graphics and/or monitor config.  Occasionally, when waking from sleep, only one monitor is recognized.  It appears to me that the other monitor is not recognized because I tried creating a `xrandr` script to re-set my modes; when this problem is _not_reproducing my script works fine to adjust the placement/resolution; but when this occurs and only one monitor is active, the same script fails with `Can't connect to display` for the monitor that is "missing".

Note it is always the same monitor affected.  I will note that while I can't say for sure this particular issue reproduced prior to the nvidia `-440` version, there have definitely been oddities with this monitor/geforce combo back when my system was `ubuntu 16.04` as well (such as loosing my `xrandr` monitor position/rotation/mode on wake from sleep, but a simple script could address that trivially).

I have looked through `dmesg` and `journalctl` around the times of sleep and wake and don't see any obvious smoking guns for real root cause (but I am no expert); will definitely upvote suggestions on other ways to triage - but i would like to know how to force a plug/re-enumeration/etc.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you attach the script running `xrandr` on wake from sleep? Have you tried adding `--auto` to that `xrandr` command?

Comment: @dezza this finally reproduced for me again; my memory was off - error is actually `Can't open display`.  I've edited that sentence above.  Here is the script.  Again, works as intended when this issue is not reproducing, including after I physically unplug/replug as described: `xrandr --output DP-2 --mode 3840x2160 --pos 0x0 --rotate normal --rate 60.00     --output DP-0 --mode 3840x2160 --pos 3840x0 --rotate right --rate 60.00`